# How to update proprietary software?

Tags: updates, update-manager, proprietary

If I have Master PDF Editor x.x.1 and there is x.x.2 available.

Do I just get the latest version and install it on top of the old one or do I delete the old one first to get rid of the unnecessary files and then install the new one?

Comment: You can directly install the latest version. It should overwrite the older version.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the latest version from the official website and then install it using the default package installer

```
apt install ./master-pdf-editor-x.xx.x_qt5.amd64.deb
```

your application purge the older and updates to the newer one.

Comment: Will there remain any unnecessary files from the previous installation?

Comment: Depends on the app. With proprietary apps, you need to check with the publisher. https://code-industry.net/contact/

Comment: @shiu'sho Please mark this answer as correct